# Dagger2 sub-component confusion in Android

Tags: android, dependencies, dagger-2

**My Goal :**

To understand how scope works and how to Implement a `UserScope` that I can use over multiple Activities and reset/create a new one as required.

**Methods I am using :**

1. This Blog: http://frogermcs.github.io/building-userscope-with-dagger2/
   It apparently explains the same thing that i am trying to achieve here.
2. Official Docs
   http://frogermcs.github.io/building-userscope-with-dagger2/

**Quick brief on Blog**

[image]

Obviously, There is `UserModule` and `UserComponent`. Author has wrapped the creation of `UserComponent` under `UserManager` which has `ApplicationScope`. So `UserManager` is available at time of log in. when login is successful `UserComponent` is initialized via `UserManager`. Simple logic.

Now this already initialized `@UserScope` is used in couple of Activities, as you can see in the picture.

**What I am struggling to understand**

Take a look at `UserComponent`.

```
public interface UserComponent {

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    interface Builder {
        Builder sessionModule(UserModule userModule);

        UserComponent build();
    }

    UserDetailsActivityComponent plus(UserDetailsActivityComponent.UserDetailsActivityModule module);

    RepositoriesListActivityComponent plus(RepositoriesListActivityComponent.RepositoriesListActivityModule module);

    LogoutManager logoutManager();
}
```

Specifically `UserDetailsActivityComponent` and `RepositoriesListActivityComponent` are created through `UserComponent`. Like this,

```
@Override
    protected void onUserComponentSetup(UserComponent userComponent) {
        userComponent.plus(new UserDetailsActivityComponent.UserDetailsActivityModule(this)).inject(this);
    }
```

So they first get pre-created in `UserComponent` through `UserManager` and then it calls `onUserComponentSetup` which then creates the appropriate Component and injects the current Activity.

**I fail to comprehend with this pattern mentioned above,** as I have read in the docs that we use `plus(InjectionToBeDoneOn i)` when we need the injection on a particular instance of `InjectionToBeDoneOn`. But why inject this Activity via this Component? What does this accomplish? Wouldn't it make sense to do this the conventional way in `onCreate()` of the activity with `DaggerXYZComponent().Builder().Build().inject(activity)`?

Also, I am missing decent material of how `UserScope` is implemented in Android which has life span from log-in to log-out but not bigger than the `@Singleton` scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> we use `plus(InjectionToBeDoneOn i)` when we need the injection on particular instance of InjectionToBeDoneOn

Not quite. A component has basically 3 kinds of methods

1. `SomeDependency provideDependency()` which just creates / provides some dependency to subcomponents, or for manual retrieval (basically a getter)
2. `void inject(MyAndroidFrameworkClass object)` that injects an object with its dependencies
3. `SomeSubComponent plus(SubComponentModule module)` that creates a subcomponent, adding additional modules

You're mixing up 2. and 3. here.

```
// user scoped component
userComponent
    // create a subcomponent (UserDetailsActivityComponent)
    .plus(new UserDetailsActivityComponent.UserDetailsActivityModule(this))
    // use the UserDetailsActivityComponent that was just created and inject with it
   .inject(this);
```

`UserDetailsActivityComponent` is a subcomponent of `UserComponent`, which is why the userComponent gets extended `.plus(somemodule)` to create a subcomponent. If your submcomponent does not need additional modules you can also just use `.plus()` because to Dagger the important thing is the *return type* or signature in general.

- If it returns another component, then it creates a SubComponent.
- If it hast one parameter and returns `void` or the parameters type, then it is an inject method
- If it has no parameters and returns some type is is a provides method (1.) to expose some dependency

> but why inject this Activity via this Component? What does this accomplish?

If you were to create `UserDetailsActivityComponent` from scratch, it would only see and know about what it can provide *itself*. If you have some `@Singleton` somewhere it could not access any of it, because it is not part of the object graph.

A subcomponent *extends* another component, adding to the object graph. If you have a `@Singleton A` and your UserComponentn needs `A` to provide `B`, with a subcomponent this will work, without it you will get a *cannot be provided* error.

Dagger is no magic. It really just builds up a directed graph and checks whether everything is fine. It will complain if some dependencies have cyclic dependencies on one another or if some part of the graph doesn't have access to dependencies it need.

Your `UserComponent` holds your userdata. For simplicity lets say it holds the `UserName`. Now `UserDetailsActivity` might want to display `UserName`, but it needs some way to get it.

By using the `@Singleton AppComponent` as a parent you'd have access to some Apis, but not the user scoped ones. You could move the user scoped objects into the `@Singleton AppComponent`, but then you'd either have to recreate the `AppComponent` every time the user changes (which kind of defeats the purpose of declaring it `@Singleton`, or you'd have to find some other means to update / change the user.

If you want to do it the Dagger way, you create a UserComponent that *adds* the User to the graph. That way subcomponents can access it and do their user things.

When the user changes you have to make sure to destroy any activities / fragments that used the UserComponent, and you just recreate everything—with a new user.

> wont it make sense to do in conventional way in `OnCreate()` of the activity with `DaggerXYZComponent().Builder().Build().inject(activity)`

You can do that of course. The author just put the calls to `app.getAppcomponent().getUserManager().getUserComponent()` or something like this into their `BaseActivity` and `BaseUserActivity` so that you wouldn't have to repeat the same lines of code every time. This method will basically still be called in `onCreate`, it just enables you to use the components directly, without fetching them every single time.
You can obviously remove those template methods and inline everything in `onCreate`, leading to duplicated code, making maintenance harder in the long run.

> i am missing decent material of how `UserScope` is implemented in android which has life span from log-in to log-out but not bigger than `@SingleTon` scope.

Android doesn't help and it's your job to clean up after yourself. If the user changes you purge everything the UserComponent and its SubComponents touched, and recreate it with the new user.

You will have to store the UserComponent with the current user either in the Application class, some "real" singleton, or some "Manager" in the application component with a `@Singleton` scope. Every approach has their own benefits I guess.

Scopes just point out to Dagger that one object should exist within a Scope only *once*. It doesn't matter what you name it, or how many objects are in the Scope. Dagger only needs them to ensure that there are no dependency cycles.

Comment: That makes sense. thank you.
but `UserModule` does not have `subcomponents` attribute for  `UserDetailsActivityComponent`, as its mentioned in the Docs, but still `UserDetailsActivityComponent` can serve as subcomponent of `UserComponent`?

Comment: @Ankit I don't quite understand what you are talking about. Could you elaborate your question?

Comment: this is from the doc,
`To add a subcomponent to a parent component, add the subcomponent class to the subcomponents attribute of a @Module that the parent component installs. Then the subcomponent’s builder can be requested from within the parent.` i.e. `@Module(subcomponents = RequestComponent.class)`

Comment: @Ankit Oh that's what you mean. I think this was added in a later Dagger version (modules with subcomponents, and builders in general). Both ways will create a submodule, yes. I don't know which one would be the preferred way, but if you decide on using the Android Injection part of Dagger you will have to use the module attribute way.